# Why spread syntax can't work in navigator's position object?

Tags: javascript

The `Position` object can't work with spread syntax

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  console.log(position);

  for( var i in position) {
     console.log(i + ":" + position[i]);
  }

  const d = { ...position };
  console.log(d);
  const { coords } = position;
  console.log(coords);
});
```

In this code, `d` should be shallow copy `position`

At last,`d` is an empty object.

Comment: The properties of `position` are not enumerable - confirm this by `console.log(Object.keys(position));` - results in an *empty* array

Comment: @JaromandaX—because, as Barmar says, a *position* object doesn't appear to have any own properties. The *coords* and *timestamp* properties are inherited. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - oh, I thought it was a case of enumerable only, but yeah ... that kinda makes sense

Comment: @JaromandaX They're enumerable or they wouldn't show up in `for (var i in position)`

Comment: @Barmar - gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spread syntax only expands to the the object's own enumerable properties. The  properties of `Position` are defined using getters in the prototype, they're not ordinary, own properties in the object itself.

If you do `console.log(Object.keys(position))` it will show an empty array for the same reason.

`for-in` iterates over the object's enumerable properties, it's not restricted to own properties. So it includes the inherited properties. So you'll have to do the shallow copy with a loop:

```
d = {}
for (i in position) {
  d[i] = position[i];
}
```

Comment: "*The properties of Position are defined using getters in the prototype*". Do you have a reference for that? The W3C Geolocation API specification doesn't define implementation details, and I can't see it at [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position) either (which isn't that surprising and even if it was, would not necessarily cover all implementations), unless it's inferred by the phrase "*available only in secure contexts*"

Comment: I don't have a reference, I saw it by doing `console.log(position.__proto__)`. You can see `get coords` and `get timestamp` there.

Comment: Yes, you are right.The `coords ` and `timestamp` is come from `__proto__`.
And I make demo, It can make the same status:

`e = {get abc() {return 'a'}, xxx: 3};r = {};r.__proto__ = e;console.log(Object.keys(r)); Object.keys(r.__proto__)`...But this behavior is very strange..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, realise that the default timeout for getCurrentPosition is infinite(!). That means that your error handler will never be called if getCurrentPosition hangs somewhere on the back end.

To ensure that you get a timeout, add the optional third parameter to your call to getCurrentPosition, for example, if you want the user to wait no more than 10 seconds before giving them a clue what is happening, use:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,errorCallback,{timeout:10000});
```

Due to timeout reason may be you are not able to get the output of position. Once you get `position` data, you may try like:

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log(position);
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    }, function(error) {
       console.log(error);
    });
```

Once above code works properly, you may convert them into arrow function and able to use your code.