# Axios unable to post navigator getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, axios, navigator

I'm just trying to post the users current position, I can console log the value returned

```
{
    "coords": {
        "accuracy": 3628,
        "altitude": null,
        "altitudeAccuracy": null,
        "heading": null,
        "latitude": ---,
        "longitude": ---,
        "speed": null
    },
    "timestamp": 1597499108300
}
```

but once axios tries to post the value to the API the value is changed to `{}`

This happens no matter the name of the key for the value, eg I can put `"fakekeyname": location` or anything else and the value is changed to `{}`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            function start() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    (location) => {
                        console.log(location)

                        axios.post("http://localhost:1337/v1/posts", {
                            location,
                        })
                    },
                    (error) => console.error(error)
                )
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is that the "object" returned is actually defined by getters which is why they don't work with the axios post. Sources are this comment and stack overflow post I found:

I'm going to guess it's because you haven't converted it to an ordinary object. Have you tried extracting out the data that you need to send via the POST request?
Eg: {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude}

[Why spread syntax can't work in navigator's position object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049446/why-spread-syntax-cant-work-in-navigators-position-object)